# How can I package NextJS app into an installable desktop app using Electron and electron-builder?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, electron, packaging, electron-builder

I'm trying to create desktop installable files for macOS, Linux & Windows. I already have a webapp built in NextJS & want to convert that app in desktop apps using electron & electron-builder packages.

I've created this electron.js file in my root directory.

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1280, height: 760 })
  mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`)
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => mainWindow = null)
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

& this electron-builder.yml file

```
appId: com.example.messagingapp
productName: MApp
directories:
  output: dist
files:
  - package.json
  - electron.js
  - .next/**
  - dist/**/*
  - node_modules/**/*
  - components/**/*
  - constants/**
  - graphql/**/*
  - lib/**/*
  - pages/**/*
  - public/**
  - src/**/*
  - styles/**
  - .env
  - store/**/*

extends: null
mac:
  target: dmg
  category: your.app.category

win:
  target: nsis

linux:
  target: deb
```

& using this script to create the installable files
`"package-app": "next build && electron-builder"`

This installable files are being created but are not showing anything. Just a blank HTML page with nothing in the body.

I want it to create installable file with app pages running in it.

Comment: First thing to do is open the Dev Tools (`Ctrl+Shift+I`/`Cmd+Shift+I` on Mac) from the blank page window and see if you can see any errors in the Console and/or the Network tab. If so, add them to your question. Also, check the files that your build commands produce. Your `mainWindow.loadURL` call will be somewhere in the built files. Now check if the relative path you pass into the call as seen from the built file still matches up with your built `index.html`. If not, you need to adjust that path in your sources to match the built path.